# How does [Authorize] attribute enhance Azure App Service (web app) authentication/authorization

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I published a web app to Azures App Services. I used the App Service's Authentication/Authorization feature to provide security. I successfully added Active Directory features to my web service (and desktop client). It seemed to work very well. Couldn't access data from a browser or desktop client without signing in to the AD.

This was all before I added the [Authorize] attribute to any of the controllers in the API!

So, what will [Authorize] do (or add) to security in my web api. It seems to already be locked up by configuring the Authentication/Authorization features of the web app in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what will [Authorize] do (or add) to security in my web api.

Using [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy), you could check the source code about [AuthorizeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd460317(v=vs.118)) under `System.Web.Mvc.dll`. The core code for authorization check looks like this:

```
protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (httpContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
    }
    IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (_usersSplit.Length > 0 && !_usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (_rolesSplit.Length > 0)
    {
        string[] rolesSplit = _rolesSplit;
        IPrincipal principal = user;
        if (!rolesSplit.Any(principal.IsInRole))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The main process would check `httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, then check whether the current user name, user role is authorized or not when you specifying the allowed Users,Roles.

For [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview)(Easy Auth) which is implemented as a native IIS module. Details you could follow  [Architecture of Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://cgillum.tech/2016/02/01/architecture-of-azure-app-service-authentication-authorization/).

> It seemed to work very well. Couldn't access data from a browser or desktop client without signing in to the AD.
>
> This was all before I added the [Authorize] attribute to any of the controllers in the API!

Based on your description, I assumed that you set **Action to take when request is not authenticated** to **Log in with Azure Active Directory** instead of **Allow Anonymous requests (no action)** under your Azure Web App Authentication/Authorization blade.

Per my understanding, you could just leverage App Service Authentication / Authorization which provides built-in authentication and authorization support for you without manually adding middleware in your code for authentication. App service authentication would validate the request before your code can process it. So, for additional custom authorization check in your code, you could define your custom authorize class which inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute` to implement your custom processing.

```html
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //TODO:
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //TODO:
    }
}
```

Then, decorate the specific action(s) or controller(s) as follows:

```html
[CustomAuthorize]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
   //TODO:
}
```

Comment: OK. So that helps a lot. To get started I guess that I should start by adding User, Role and Policy conditions to the [Authorize] constructor. And of course set up the Users and Roles in AD. Let's see where that leads. Thanks.

Comment: You need to define app roles and assign role to the specific user in AAD via Azure Portal, then construct the Authorize with the corresponding usernames or roles for your action(s) or controller(s). For detailed tutorial, you could follow [Authorization in a web app using Azure AD application roles & role claims](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/).

Answer (score 0):

App Service's Authentication/Authorization feature is Based on IIS Level. [Authorize] attribute is based on our code level. Both of this can do Authentication, if you used both of them, it means that there are two levels of authentication in your web app.

Here is a picture that helps you understand them:

[image]